# how to begin to understand KML by analyzing the XSD

Tags: xml, google-maps, dictionary, xsd

I have no experience with KML or XSD. I understand sort of what KML is. it's an XML used to generate a google map.

this site supplies the XSD information for the KML.

i  opened the XSD file and i will post only a small portion of it because it's huge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:xal="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0"
  targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  version="2.2.0">

  <annotation>
    <appinfo>ogckml22.xsd 2008-01-23</appinfo>
    <documentation>XML Schema Document for OGC KML version 2.2. Copyright (c)
      2008 Open Geospatial Consortium, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    </documentation>
  </annotation>  

  <!-- import atom:author and atom:link -->
  <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    schemaLocation="atom-author-link.xsd"/>

  <!-- import xAL:Address -->
  <import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ciq:xsdschema:xAL:2.0"
    schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/election/external/xAL.xsd"/>

  <!-- KML field types (simple content) -->

  <simpleType name="anglepos90Type">
    <restriction base="double">
      <minInclusive value="0.0"/>
      <maxInclusive value="90.0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="angle90Type">
    <restriction base="double">
      <minInclusive value="-90"/>
      <maxInclusive value="90.0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="anglepos180Type">
    <restriction base="double">
      <minInclusive value="0.0"/>
      <maxInclusive value="180.0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="angle180Type">
    <restriction base="double">
      <minInclusive value="-180.0"/>
      <maxInclusive value="180.0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="angle360Type">
    <restriction base="double">
      <minInclusive value="-360.0"/>
      <maxInclusive value="360.0"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="altitudeModeEnumType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="clampToGround"/>
      <enumeration value="relativeToGround"/>
      <enumeration value="absolute"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="colorType">
    <annotation>
      <documentation><![CDATA[

        aabbggrr

        ffffffff: opaque white
        ff000000: opaque black

        ]]></documentation>
    </annotation>
    <restriction base="hexBinary">
      <length value="4"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="coordinatesType">
    <list itemType="string"/>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="colorModeEnumType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="normal"/>
      <enumeration value="random"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="dateTimeType">
    <union memberTypes="dateTime date gYearMonth gYear"/>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="displayModeEnumType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="default"/>
      <enumeration value="hide"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="gridOriginEnumType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="lowerLeft"/>
      <enumeration value="upperLeft"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
  <simpleType name="itemIconStateType">
    <list itemType="kml:itemIconStateEnumType"/>
  </simpleType>

  <simpleType name="itemIconStateEnumType">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="open"/>
      <enumeration value="closed"/>
      <enumeration value="error"/>
      <enumeration value="fetching0"/>
      <enumeration value="fetching1"/>
      <enumeration value="fetching2"/>
```

i don't really understand how to use these things to generate a map.

i was wondering if you could point me into the right direction on what exactly XSD is, and how i can use this documentation to generate a nice KML file to display a valid google map?

Comment: The complete and official version of the KML 2.2.0 XSD schema that you have excerpted is located at http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd . That said, the schema is not the way to learn KML. Definitely start with the KML Tutorial link provided by @Pangea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Артём, once you have begun developing some KML examples, you can check them for correctness by using the KML Validator generously provided by Galdos: http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm . When the validator finds something wrong, it will give you useful hints for fixing the problem. (The validator uses the [KML 2.2.0 XSD schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd) in part to do its job.)

Answer (score 2):

Tough one. You're right, schemas for vocabularies like KML tend to be huge, and they are often indigestible (there are rare exceptions that are written in a literary programming style). I wouldn't start from the schema. There seems to be a KML tutorial online - have you exhausted that?

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat earlier and the [KML Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) and Reference documentation provided by Google helped me a lot.